# KnexJS | Migration | raw transforming the query unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, knex.js

We are migrating the SP (Stored Proc) to new version. SP have statement as `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() As Id`.
Now when we run the migration on the database to move it to latest, everything in the SP is good except the above mentioned select statement.
`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() As Id` changes to `SELECT 0 As Id`.

- We have a lambda function, which takes care of creating and/or upgrading the database to the latest migration.
- When we call this lambda to create new database as well as to upgrade existing database from local environment (serverless-offline) i works fine.
- When we call this lambda (deployed on the AWS) this behaves differently,

when we create database, it works fine,
when trying to upgrade an existing database, it converts the LAST_INSERT_ID() to 0.

We have enabled debugging in the knex, In the logs it looks all find, but when we check the SP in the database, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is converted to `0`.

**Observations**

- we are not doubting on the AWS infra side, as it works fine when we create a new database.
- even the script is all fine, as it also works fine for other cases.
- not doubting on the database user permission, as it works again fine for other cases.
- even when we call the lambda with debugging enabled, which is deployed in AWS, logs looks as expected.

We are using the `raw` function to Drop and create the SP.

More details are added in the bug ticket in the github repo
https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/5259